# Obtain Data properties from class with OWL API JAVA

Tags: java, api, object, range, owl

I'm trying to get the data properties of a class with the OWL API of java (http://owlapi.sourceforge.net) but I can't get it.

For example The class "person" has a data properties "hasGender" whose range is : {"F"^^xsd:string , "M"^^xsd:string}

```
    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&lico;hasGender">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&lico;Patient"/>
    <rdfs:range>
        <rdfs:Datatype>
            <owl:oneOf>
                <rdf:Description>
                    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&rdf;List"/>
                    <rdf:first rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">F</rdf:first>
                    <rdf:rest>
                        <rdf:Description>
                            <rdf:type rdf:resource="&rdf;List"/>
                            <rdf:first rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">M</rdf:first>
                            <rdf:rest rdf:resource="&rdf;nil"/>
                        </rdf:Description>
                    </rdf:rest>
                </rdf:Description>
            </owl:oneOf>
        </rdfs:Datatype>
    </rdfs:range>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&lico;hasName">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&lico;Patient"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
```

I'm trying to get the data types as follows:

```
    OWLOntologyManager man = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    OWLOntology ont;
    OWLDataFactory df = null;
    ont = man.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
    df = ont.getOWLOntologyManager().getOWLDataFactory();

    OWLClass clase = df.getOWLClass(Class);

    Set<OWLDatatype> dataType = clase.getDatatypesInSignature();
```

How could I extract this property and range?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Classes do not have properties in OWL - what you've tried will get datatype IRIs in the signature of an object, bit as the object is an entity its signature contains only a class IRI.

What you really are looking at is data properties that have the class as part of their domain, so you need to get all data property domain axioms from your ontology (probably including imports) and check if the domain subsumes the class - i.e., the class appears in the signature of the axiom, or if you're using a reasoner, whether the class has the domain as a superclass.